# Is the ASV Bible version Public Domain in Canada? Any other Bibles Public domain in Canada?

Tags: bible, copyright

I have found on [Biblegateway.com](https://support.biblegateway.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001403507-What-Bibles-on-Bible-Gateway-are-in-the-public-domain-) that there is a list of Bibles that are in the Public Domain for the US including the ASV, but I am not sure if that also covers Canada.

Answer (score 1):

In Canada, the copyright for a work usually expires 50 years after the death of the creator, at the end of the relevant calendar year.
[https://copyright.ubc.ca/public-domain/#:~:text=In%20Canada%2C%20the%20copyright%20for,Domain%20on%201%20January%202052](https://copyright.ubc.ca/public-domain/#:%7E:text=In%20Canada%2C%20the%20copyright%20for,Domain%20on%201%20January%202052).

The ASV was originally published in 1901 and had its copyright renewed in 1929, giving it copyright end of life as 1979.  So looks like it is in Public Domain now.